# Passing an arraylist of arraylists

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-activity

I know it's a commonly asked question and I looked at the solutions online, but I am having a difficulty implementing this on my own.

I have a class which contains three variables: `Location`, `Date` and `Uri`.

I have an `Arraylist` which consists of multiple Arraylists that contains said class.

**For instance:**

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<class>>
```

I am trying to pass this onto another activity, yet unsuccessful. 
I tried both `Parcelable` and `Serializable` but none worked.

**Edit:** Source code added.

**Class documentation:**

```
public class imageHolder implements Parcelable
{
private Uri uri;
private Date date;
private Location loc;

public imageHolder(Uri uriAdd, Date dateAdded,Location imgLoc)
{
    this.uri = uriAdd;
    this.date = dateAdded;
    this.loc = imgLoc;
}


public static final Creator<imageHolder> CREATOR = new Creator<imageHolder>() {
    @Override
    public imageHolder createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new imageHolder(in);
    }

    @Override
    public imageHolder[] newArray(int size) {
        return new imageHolder[size];
    }
};

public Uri getURI() { return this.uri; }

public Date getDate() {return this.date; }

public Location getLocation() {return this.loc; };

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeSerializable(date);
    parcel.writeParcelable(uri,i);
    parcel.writeParcelable(loc, i);
}

protected imageHolder(Parcel in) {
    date = (java.util.Date) in.readSerializable();
    uri = in.readParcelable(Uri.class.getClassLoader());
    loc = in.readParcelable(Location.class.getClassLoader());
}

}
```

**First activity:**

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<imageHolder>> sepImages = new ArrayList<ArrayList<imageHolder>>();
    sepImages = groupPics(images);


    Intent nextActivity = new Intent(loadImages.this, storiesScreen.class);
    nextActivity.putExtra("images",images);
    startActivity(nextActivity);
    finishActivity(0);
```

**Second activity:**

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<imageHolder>> sepImages = 
(ArrayList<ArrayList<imageHolder>>) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("images");
Log.d("stories","test");
```

Comment: Can you post source code? Btw, if its a lot of data its better to use a repository type structure. Passing lot of data is not really what serialization/parcelable is for and you can in fact have issues because there is an upper limit of parcelable data.

Comment: @breakline Hey, thanks for replying. I have added the source code now. It should be a good amount of data passed between these activities. I will look into the repository type structure soon, although I have never heard of it.

Comment: Not an answer but just some Java Style coding tips: Start your classes with Uppercase. Variables are correct starting with lowercase and using the camel case style. Example: `ImageHolder` for class `imageHolder` for variable.

Comment: Is it your intention to pass "images" and not "sepImages"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best thing to do here would be to create a new class that implements `Parcelable` and pass instances of this new class between activities.

```
public class ParcelableListOfLists implements Parcelable {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<imageHolder>> listOfLists;

    public ParcelableListOfLists(ArrayList<ArrayList<imageHolder>> listOfLists) {
        this.listOfLists = listOfLists;
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<imageHolder>> getListOfLists() {
        return listOfLists;
    }

    // parcelable implementation here
}
```

Once you have this class, you can be in full control of *how* your data is parceled, and that lets you do some things that you won't be able to do with the Android built-in offerings.

Here's one way you could parcel a list of lists:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    if (listOfLists != null) {
        dest.writeInt(listOfLists.size());

        for (ArrayList<imageHolder> list : listOfLists) {
            dest.writeTypedList(list);
        }
    } else {
        dest.writeInt(-1);
    }
}
```

And on the other side, you can recreate the list of lists like this:

```
public ParcelableListOfLists(Parcel in) {
    int size = in.readInt();

    if (size != -1) {
        this.listOfLists = new ArrayList<>(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            ArrayList<imageHolder> list = in.createTypedArrayList(imageHolder.CREATOR);
            listOfLists.add(list);
        }
    } else {
        this.listOfLists = null;
    }
}
```

With all of this together, you can pass your list of lists between activities like this:

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(loadImages.this, storiesScreen.class);
nextActivity.putExtra("images", new ParcelableListOfLists(images));
startActivity(nextActivity);
```

and retrieve them in the next activity like this:

```
ParcelableListOfLists plol = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("images");
ArrayList<ArrayList<imageHolder>> images = plol.getListOfLists();
```

Comment: Hey. I am going to give it a try. My question is meanwhile, performance wise, is it not going to be time-consuming when I have to copy and then re-create the list? Considering I could be using hundreds of images.

Comment: @Tomer depending on how "big" each `imageHolder` is, copying hundreds could be nearly instantaneous or very slow. However, anything you parcel and send via `Intent.putExtra()` *must* be "small", because otherwise you'll hit the binder transaction size limit. As long as your data is within this size limit, I doubt you have to worry about performance.

Comment: I have managed to pass the lists between activities and also moved everything to AsynTasks, yet at some point the screen becomes black for about 7 seconds before the next activity shows up. Something does consume a lot of time which makes it go black, but that's another issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use Gson too.

In your **build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
```

In the **first activity**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(yourObject);
intent.putExtra("yourKey", json);
```

In the **second activity**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourObject yourObject = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("yourKey"), YourObject.class);
```

Easy and fast.

Comment: I tried using your code yet but it ends up with sepImages as NULL on the second activity. On this command line:
YourObject yourObject = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("yourKey"), YourObject.class);
What is meant to be my object.class? The ArrayList or the imageHolder?

Comment: If you are putting an Object of type ArrayList you have to use ArrayList.class! You can use List.class too and i bet you can use all with Object.class too :D

Comment: Gives me the same error. Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Comment: I think that's because all sub classes and inner sub classes must implement Serializable.

Comment: Your ImageHolder class must implements Serializable, then use ArrayList or LinkedList that implements Serializable!

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Your **Model**

```
public class ImageHolder implements Serializable {

    // Use String here, to avoid serialization problems
    private String uri;
    private Date date;
    private Location loc;

    public ImageHolder() {
    }

    public ImageHolder(String uri, Date date, Location loc) {
        this.uri = uri;
        this.date = date;
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Location getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(Location loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ImageHolder{" +
                "uri=" + uri +
                ", date=" + date +
                ", loc=" + loc +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Create a **Container** class

```
public class Container implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<ImageHolder> list;

    public Container() {
    }

    public Container(ArrayList<ImageHolder> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public ArrayList<ImageHolder> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<ImageHolder> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Container{" +
                "list=" + list +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Your **First Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ImageHolder imageHolder0 = new ImageHolder("http://www.stackoverflow.com", new Date(), new Location("test0"));
        ImageHolder imageHolder1 = new ImageHolder("http://www.google.com", new Date(), new Location("test1"));

        ArrayList<ImageHolder> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(imageHolder0);
        list.add(imageHolder1);

        Container container = new Container(list);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(container);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("yourKey", json);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Your **second activity**

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = TestActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Container container = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("yourKey"), Container.class);

        Log.d(TAG, "OK?" + container.getList().toString());

        // Here convert String uri Fields to Uri Objects
        // Example:
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(container.getList().get(0).getUri());
    }
}
```

Logcat result: `08-01 11:10:22.097 6671-6671/it.darksurfer.english.template D/TestActivity: OK?[ImageHolder{uri=http://www.stackoverflow.com, date=Wed Aug 01 11:10:21 GMT+02:00 2018, loc=Location[test0 0,000000,0,000000 acc=??? t=?!? et=?!?]}, ImageHolder{uri=http://www.google.com, date=Wed Aug 01 11:10:21 GMT+02:00 2018, loc=Location[test1 0,000000,0,000000 acc=??? t=?!? et=?!?]}]`

Obviously you can put an undefined number of others ArrayList in the list of Container class!