# Passing data from one listview to another textview

Tags: android

I have been trying to pass the contact data from my second activity's list view to my main activity's list view, upon clicking the data.But the app crashes just on clicking the *contacts* button. How do I fix this?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.artist.sender;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.id.input;
import static android.app.AlertDialog.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText itemText;
Button addButton;
Button sendText;
TextView text;
Button contact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


itemText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(itemText.getText())||(itemText.getText().length()<10)||(itemText.getText().length()>10)) {
            itemText.setError("The number is not valid.");
            return;
        } else {
            text.setText(itemText.getText().toString());
            itemText.setText("");
            return;
        }
    }
});
Button delete;
delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
delete.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
                              @Override
                              public void onClick(View view) {
                                  int con=text.getLineCount();
                                  if(con==0)
                                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No number available to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 else
                                     text.setText("");
                              }
                          });
sendText=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
sendText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String phoneno = text.getText().toString();
        int count = text.getLineCount();
        SmsManager smsMgrVar = SmsManager.getDefault();
        if (count == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No number available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    try{

                        smsMgrVar.sendTextMessage(phoneno, null, "Hey There!", null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ErrVar)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sending Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ErrVar.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 10);
                    }
                }

            }
});
contact =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);

contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,contacts.class));
        }

    }
});
String tempholder=getIntent().getStringExtra("Listviewclickvalue");
text.setText(tempholder);
}
```

**contacts.java**

```
package com.example.artist.sender;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;

public class contacts extends MainActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 444;
private ListView mListView;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private Handler updateBarHandler;

ArrayList<String> contactList;
Cursor cursor;
int counter;
ListView list;
String temp;
TextView itemText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.contacts);
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(contacts.this);
pDialog.setMessage("Reading contacts...");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.show();

mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
updateBarHandler = new Handler();

// Since reading contacts takes more time, let's run it on a separate thread.
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        getContacts();
    }
}).start();

// Set onclicklistener to the list item.
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        //TODO Do whatever you want with the list data
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item clicked : \n" + contactList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
}

private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    return true;
}
if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
{
    return true;
}
if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
} else {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
}
return false;
}

/**
* Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
*/
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                   int[] grantResults) {
if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
    if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        getContacts();
    }
}
}

public void getContacts() {

if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
    return;
}

contactList = new ArrayList<String>();

String phoneNumber = null;
// String email = null;

Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

/* Uri EmailCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;*/

StringBuffer output;

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

// Iterate every contact in the phone
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

    counter = 0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        output = new StringBuffer();

        // Update the progress message
        updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pDialog.setMessage("Reading contacts : " + counter++ + "/" + cursor.getCount());
            }
        });

        String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));

        int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

        if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

            output.append("\n First Name:" + name);


            //This is to read multiple phone numbers associated with the same contact
            Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);

            while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);

            }

            phoneCursor.close();

           /* // Read every email id associated with the contact
            Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI, null, EmailCONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);

            while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

                email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA));

                output.append("\n Email:" + email);

            }

            emailCursor.close();

            String columns[] = {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.MIMETYPE,
            };*/

            String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY +
                    " and " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.MIMETYPE + " = '" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' and " + ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contact_id;

            String[] selectionArgs = null;
            String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

            /*Cursor birthdayCur = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, columns, where, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
            Log.d("BDAY", birthdayCur.getCount()+"");
            if (birthdayCur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (birthdayCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String birthday = birthdayCur.getString(birthdayCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE));
                    output.append("Birthday :" + birthday);
                    Log.d("BDAY", birthday);
                }
            }
            birthdayCur.close();
        }*/

            // Add the contact to the ArrayList
            contactList.add(output.toString());
        }

        // ListView has to be updated using a ui thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contact_text, R.id.text1, contactList);
                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

        // Dismiss the progressbar after 500 millisecondds
        updateBarHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                pDialog.cancel();
            }
        }, 500);
    }

}


//passing the number to the mainactivity's textview through intent
list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
final String listview[] = new String[list.getCount()];
for (int j = 0; j < list.getCount(); j++) {
    View v = list.getChildAt(j);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    listview[j] = (String) tv.getText();
}
itemText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
final String number = itemText.getText().toString();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listview);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    if ((number.matches("[0-9]+"))&&(number.length()==10))
                                        temp = listview[position].toString();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(contacts.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("Listviewclickvalue", temp);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }
                            }
);
}
```

**logcat**

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.artist.sender.contacts.getContacts(contacts.java:236)
                                                                           at com.example.artist.sender.contacts$1.run(contacts.java:57)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is the logcat for the error. It keeps showing that the findViewById keeps referring to a null object whereas, I've already assigned all the variables to their respective ids.

Comment: What are you expecting `extends MainActivity` to do?

Comment: Well then how am I suppose to link it to the first activity?

Comment: Using `Intent` and `putExtra` like you're already doing? You can extend `AppCompatActivity` (like MainActivity does), but there is no reason to extend the MainActivity... If you are sharing views and layouts across two activities, that is usually the wrong idea, and you should try to use Fragments instead.

Comment: Why are you extending MainActivity? I don't think it's a good practice! You can pass objects beetween activities in different ways. Try to refer this [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615644/passing-an-arraylist-of-arraylists/51616089#51616089) for much references on how to pass data beetween different activities.